# Jmeter - How to parameterize XML request body using a file in Jmeter?

Tags: xml, jmeter, httprequest, performance-testing

I have a XML request as follows:

```
<Request>
    <Header><Log><Level>None</Level></Log></Header>
    <Body>
        <Action>
            <GetService>
                <Code>ABC</Code>
                <CodeValue>XYZ</CodeValue>
            </GetService>
        </Action>
    </Body> </Request>
```

I would like to have a file which has data for two columns - Code and CodeValue. For example,

```
Code|CodeValue
--------------
ABC|XYZ
DEF|MNO
```

How should I parameterize my XML request body so that Jmeter can dynamically use data from the file as the XML values? How should I structure my file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use csv file in JMeter to parameterize the test data.

- To get an idea, Go to this  [site](http://www.testautomationguru.com/how-to-test-rest-api-using-jmeter/)  . Scorll down to the section - `CSV Data Set Config`
- Keep your data in a csv file as shown in the site. add `CSV Data Set Config` in your test plan. Update the file path.
- Update your XML as given below.

```js
<Request>
        <Header><Log><Level>None</Level></Log></Header>
        <Body>
            <Action>
                <GetService>
                    <Code>${Code}</Code>
                    <CodeValue>${CodeValue}</CodeValue>
                </GetService>
            </Action>
        </Body> </Request>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried doing the same but Jmeter is only reading the first line of the csv file. For example, from above, it is only reading ABC, XYZ. Not the rest of the file. Anything that I am missing?

Comment: @activelearner, You have to update the `Thread Group` to run forever. Update `CSV Data Set Config` to `Stop Thread on EOF`.